# `__LINE__` for method line

Tags: ruby, reflection

```
def line

  puts __LINE_ # [sic]

end

line()
```

prints `"2"`. But it should print `"5"` because the method is called there. Why can I change that problem? It should spend the row was written in `__LINE_` [sic].

Comment: What problem? What is "spend the row"?

Comment: he sould say what line is writed the method

Comment: because he writes only what line writed "__LINE_" but that souhld dont he make. (Im german)

Answer (score 1):

The `__LINE__` directive reports the line that it's located on, not the line of the caller.

For instance, this short test program:

```
def line
  puts __LINE__
end

def line_2
  puts __LINE__
end

line
line_2
```

will report this output:

```
2
6
```

That is the expected output because `__LINE__` appears on lines 2 and 6 of the source code.

Comment: I know.. And ? That interestet me not. I will that  if the method will call that then he write what line is it. Or is this not possible?